# Passing ArrayList value to a Intent.putExtra for Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, share-button

**How to pass arraylist value (samplename,  samplequote ) to the intent.putExtra.. for sharing the text..**

**In MainActivity.java**

```
 list = new ArrayList<>();

        //loading list view item with this function
        loadRecyclerViewItem();
    }

    private void loadRecyclerViewItem() {

        list.add(new MyQuote("sample name","sample quote"));
```

**In MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder myholder, int position) {
        final MyQuote myQuote = myQuoteList.get(position);
        myholder.tv_author.setText(myQuote.getAuthor());
        myholder.tv_quote.setText(myQuote.getQuotedesc());
       myholder.im_favlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_border);
       myholder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);

               intent.setType("text/plain");
               view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"send to"));

            }
        });
    }
```

**EDIT**
**after implementing Parcelable in MyQuote class.. like this when i use intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("mani" , MyQuote);....
  i'm getting "expression expected ...in MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java"**

```
public class MyQuote  implements Parcelable{

    private String author;
    private String quotedesc;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {

        parcel.writeString(quotedesc);
        parcel.writeString(author);
        }

    private MyQuote(Parcel parcel){

        quotedesc = parcel.readString();
        author = parcel.readString();

    }
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyQuote> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyQuote>(){

        @Override
        public MyQuote createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new MyQuote(parcel);

        }
        public MyQuote[] newArray(int size){
            return new MyQuote[size];
        }
    };

    //constructor initializing values
    public MyQuote(String author, String quotedesc) {
        this.quotedesc = quotedesc;
        this.author = author;
    }

    //getters
    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public String getQuotedesc() {
        return quotedesc;
    }
}
```

**I have a recycler cardview which contains quotes,and authors.. as textviews..and a sharebutton.. in each card.. when user want to share the quote, author of a particular card.. he can share the quote(string) along with author(string) to apps like messeges, whatsapp ..etc..
how can i solve this ? is implementing parcelable is correct process..for this purpose or not..if it  is correct what code should i use in onclick of a sharebutton**

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder myholder, int position) {
        final MyQuote myQuote = myQuoteList.get(position);
        myholder.tv_author.setText(myQuote.getAuthor());
        myholder.tv_quote.setText(myQuote.getQuotedesc());
       myholder.im_favlike.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_border);
       myholder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("mani" , MyQuote);
               intent.setType("text/plain");
               view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"send to"));

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement Parcelable interface in MyQuote Class and then you can send it through intent like this :-

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(key_name,your_list);

Answer (score 0):

The class of your array elements should implement `Parcelable` interface. 
After doing so, you can use `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ARRAY_LIST_KEY,fooArrayList)` to send the array list and then `Intent.getStringArrayListExtra(ARRAY_LIST_KEY)` to retrieve the list

Comment: I have a recycler cardview which contains quotes,and authors.. as textviews..and a sharebutton.. in each card.. when user want to share the quote, author of a particular card.. he can share the quote(string) along with author(string) to apps like messeges, whatsapp ..etc.. how can i solve this ? is implementing parcelable is correct process..for this purpose or not..if it is correct what code should i use in onclick of a sharebutton

Comment: I would recommend concatenating the author and quote name into one formatted string then sending it using putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, textToShare), this is if you want to share a single quote

Answer (score 0):

Hi check out this plugin [Parcelable Code Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator).

It will help you to auto generate parcelable boilerplate for a POJO class and then you can directly use it as suggested by Abhishek 
`intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(key_name, list);`